# social media feeds - client or server side requests?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, social-networking

I'm curious about what other developers do when integrating twitter, facebook and other such feed content on to a site. Do you make these requests and handle everything on the client or server side? It seems that there are a number of jquery plugins out there which handle the type of simple integrations which i tend to have to do for most sites, e.g 3 latest posts.

Previously, I was using PHP (Twitter became more complicated to integrate recently when it switched to openauth) to get content from twitter, blogger etc, but i'm wondering if there is any real need to do this when it can be done very simply with javascript. Obviously, if javascript isn't enabled then the feeds wouldn't display.

Interested to hear what people do in this situation!

Answer (score 1):

I tend to hook directly into the feeds from client-side code, unless I'm doing something complicated, need additional validation or would like to cache the results of the feed.

The rationale is that if you grab the feeds on the server, you have two download the data twice - once from the API server to your server, and once from your server to the  - whereas grabbing it directly from the API in your client-side code only results in a single HTTP request, so should arguably load quicker.

Of course, if you've got a lot of traffic, third-party services tend to rate-limit, which means you might have to look into server-side caching to be able to reliably serve the content to your visitors.

Comment: thanks, makes sense. The rate limiting issue was one of the reasons I was using PHP before, checking remaining hits and then either showing cached or live results. How do you handle the rate limit issue on the client side? Just a "tweets not available" message or something like that?

Comment: Something along those lines, yes. Unless you're using HTML5 localStorage, you can't persist tweet data between page views, so you'd just have to keep hitting the API until you hit the hourly limit.